# Unable to connect Pentaho Data Integration and SVN

Tags: windows, svn, pentaho, pdi, spoon

I'm not able to connect Pentaho Data Integration with a Subversion.

I have installed PDI CE 8.3.0.0.71 on Windows and I have unzipped the Spoongit plugin inside plugins folder in the installation directory of Pentaho.

I have installed SlikSubversion 1.12 (64 bits) and I copied libsvnjavahl-1.dll in C:\pdi-ce-8.3.0.0-371\data-integration\libswt\win64.

I have installed jdk 8u231.

When I try to clone a repository, I always get this error:

*org.tigris.subversion.svnclientadapter.SVNClientException: Javahl client adapter is not available*

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Edit: removed original comment after reading the instructions :-) Falling back to the default: Double check which version of Java is being used to RUN PDI. You'd be suprised how often some 32-bit version is being found elsewhere on the computer.

Comment: I have verified that Pentaho is using Java 64-bit version.

Comment: I've tried it using PDI 8.1 and a local SVN repository created with TortoiseSVN, did not get any errors, but also did not get it to work. Git integration does work normally.

Comment: But, have you followed same steps as me??

Comment: I already had PDI and SpoonGit. I installed SlikSVN and copied over the dll to the win64 per the instructions. If I then switch to the Git view and either clone or add a repository, nothing happens. I was able to clone a public repository using just svn command, outside of PDI